# Translate site google API romanian

Tags: google-translate

I am interested in translating my site in Romanian using the google API. Can somebody tell me how I can get the code for Romanian?
I found how to implement it but I don't know I should search to get the code.
Sorry if it is a dumb question , but I'm a beginner.
Thanks, Khoie Aryan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/languages
Here you can find a list with all the supported languages.
The ISO-639-1 Code for Romanian is simply ro.
GL with your site!

Comment: Yeah I found it in the attached document. Really coudn't find it. It's working now. Thanks!